# Kubuntu 15.10 won't boot from live USB on my Samsung rf-511 laptop

Tags: boot, kubuntu, live-usb

I want to try **Kubuntu 15.10** and that is why I have created a **live USB** of the **kubuntu 15.10** iso through **UNetBootin.**

I have used the same pen drive to install my present OS (**Lubuntu 15.10**) and had live Ubuntu 15.10 installed just before I formatted it to install **Kubuntu 15.10**.

The same pen drive with **Kubuntu 15.10** boots from USB on my **HP envy m6** laptop.

On the other hand my **Samsung rf-511** laptop has booted all OS'es apart from  **Kubuntu 15.10**.

So I am not exactly able to pinpoint where the problem lies.

For info, my pen drive has been formatted in **FAT 16** version.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Third party tools like Unetbootin often don't prepare and create the Ubuntu Live media properly.

You can create the USB media by using the built-in **disks tool** in Ubuntu.
Open it and select **Restore Disk Image** from the menu on the top right.
Choose the **ISO file** and the **USB drive** to write it to and start restoring.

If you want to make it in Windows use the **diskpart** tool.
Open **command prompt as administator** and execute:

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk * (* = number of USB drive)  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=** (** = select a free drive letter)
```

Mount the ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.