# Ubuntu Installation Issues - ACPI PCC Probe Failed

Tags: acpi

Currently I wish to set up a dual boot configuration with Windows 10 as main and Ubuntu as my secondary OS. However, every time I try booting from the bootable Ubuntu USB (Corsair Voyager 32GB) I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYUgh.jpg
The same error happens on both the LTS version and the 15.10 version of Ubuntu. The USB boot has also been tested working on 2 other PCs (Not ASUS motherboards), which leads me to believe the issue is caused by not having any onboard or CPU graphics, but only dedicated GPU (GTX 980 Ti).

The error occurs right after pressing the "Install Ubuntu" option, and pressing any keys on the keyboard doesn't advance or provoke anything. It's just frozen.
It's also worth noting that pressing the `"Try Ubuntu without installing"` option also triggers this error. So I'm not even able to boot on a pre-installed Ubuntu USB.

Has anyone got any ideas to what this could be? I have the latest BIOS version and I've also tried with defaulted F5 BIOS settings, same issue.
I have no BIOS options pertaining to ACPI.

List of hardware, in case you need to know for troubleshooting:

```
CPU: Intel i7 5930k
RAM: 4x 4GB Corsair Dominator Platinum DDR4
GPU: EVGA GTX 980 Ti
Motherboard: Asus Rampage V Extreme
PSU: Corsair AX1500i
SSD: Samsung 950 512GB Pro M.2 NVMe SSD (Windows installation)
SSD(2): OCZ Vertex 4 256GB
SSD(3): OCZ Vertex 4 256GB (Ubuntu is going on this one)
Monitor(1): Asus VG248QE 144hz 1080p
Monitor(2): BenQ 2410t 120hz 1080p
Headphones: Philips Fidelio X1
Mouse: Logitech G500s
Keyboard: Corsair K70 RGB MX Brown
USB: Corsair Voyager GT 3.0 32GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. `ACPI PCC probe failed` literally happens on 50-75% of Linux systems. It means nothing to a new user, and won't do anything bad. If you have that message, then on other distributions like Mint, you most likely will also get it. No worries, and a merry christmas.

Comment: I know this is a common "error message" to get during booting Ubuntu, but my issue is that the booting process freezes with this error and doesn't continue.

Comment: @Andreas Huh, i don't know then. Graphics card maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably are assuming right, this most probably is a compatibility issue.
Boot from the Ubuntu USB (Corsair Voyager) installation media you have created.

Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing** in the boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` **to the end of the linux line** ... then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

After having installed the OS repeat the same (Ubuntu entry) on first system start.
The first thing you should do is to install the proprietary NVIDIA drivers to Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your effort to help me. Your suggestion did however not yield any improvements for me. I did as you described and pressed F10 to boot, then the exact same error came up again (freezing the boot process). I took a picture of the "e" window with your settings, just to make sure I did it correctly. http://i.imgur.com/V7AbDtm.jpg

Comment: @Andreas : Please remove the "--" from the parameter. In case it still freezes, replace nouveau.modeset=0 with nomodeset ! :)

Comment: I have now tried without the "--" and the suggested two options, but they both also fail. :(
Nouveau.modeset=0 http://i.imgur.com/MnDRE57.jpg & nomodeset http://i.imgur.com/MTfVFkn.jpg

Comment: @Andreas : I am running out of ideas ... maybe the installation media is not configured properly ? :)

Comment: It's just weird I'm able to use it on 2 other machines (different hardware). I've also tried installing the USB media with both "Universal USB Installer" & "LinuxLive USB Creator". Also another USB key. All scenarios give me the error... :(

Comment: @Andreas : Please read these instructions : http://askubuntu.com/questions/690062/kubuntu-15-10-wont-boot-from-live-usb-on-my-samsung-rf-511-laptop/690066#690066 - maybe it can help ... :)